# file not found | upload data to mySQL - Java

Tags: java, mysql, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to upload Images to my MySQL-DB by using this [Insert file data into MySQL database using JDBC](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/insert-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-jdbc)

But I always get the error: File or Directory not found. I copied the file in the workspace, now on the desktop... I don'f find the problem or am I doing sth really wrong? My function is the following:

```
String error = "Upload failed!";
String success = "Upload success!";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager
    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + serverIP + "/db?"
        + "user=" + sqluser
        + "&password=" + sqlpassword
        + "&useUnicode=true"
        + "&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
        + "&autoReconnect=true"
        + "&failOverReadOnly=false"
        + "&maxReconnects=10");

String filePath = "‪C:\\Users\\chris_000\\Desktop\\test.png";

try {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO pictures (pic_url) values (?)";

    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

    statement.setBlob(1, inputStream);
    statement.executeUpdate();

    int row = statement.executeUpdate();
    if (row > 0) {
        System.out.println("A contact was inserted with photo image.");
    }

    conn.close();

    return success;
} catch (Exception e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);

    return sw.toString();
}
```

Thx for help in advance

Edit: received-StackTrace:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪C:\Benutzer\chris_000\Desktop\test.png (Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at Database.MysqlPicture.uploadPic(MysqlPicture.java:56)
at Functions.UploadImage.uploadImage(UploadImage.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Why do you call executeUpdate twice?

Comment: Try to remove the first statement.executeUpdate();

Comment: add the stacktrace also

Comment: i removed the first executeUpdate, thx. StackTrace is added.

Comment: double check your path ‪C:\Benutzer\chris_000\Desktop\test.png

Comment: @Knuspakeks, In your code, you have used filepath like this C:\\Users\\chris_000\\Desktop\\test.png. but I am seeing something else in  stacktrace [C:\Benutzer\chris_000\Desktop\test.png]. Please check whether file exists in that path.

Comment: "Benutzer" is the German word for. I tried "Users" and "Benutzer"... same error :(

Comment: @Knuspakeks, can you please check whether that file exists in that path mentioned in your code

Comment: file exists: http://i.imgur.com/abgveke.jpg

Comment: Try to move it under C: drive and test it out

Comment: already tried... no success... I keep u guys informed when i find the solution